# Selecting another table rows based on values that are semi-colon delimited and stored in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

My question title might seem confusing because I am unable to form a logic here. I don't have much knowledge of Stored Procedures so there might be some feature of SQL that I am missing. My problem is that I have a table in a SQL Server database. One of its columns contains semi-colon separated values. These values are actually the identity of the rows of another table. So, my task is to get these IDs from this semi-colon separated list one by one of all rows that satifies a `Name` column value and get the rows of another table with the same ID. I am posting a general algorithm (based on C# and SQL) that I want to implement in SQL Server Stored Procedure:

```
DECLARE X AS ROWS = GetRowsFromTable1ByName('ABC');
DECLARE RESULT AS ROWS;
DECLARE Y AS ARRAY;
FOREACH(ID1 in X)     //ID1 denotes ID column from Table1
{
   Y = ID1.Split(';');
   FOREACH(ID2 in Y)  //ID2 denotes ID column from Array Y
   {
      RESULT.ADDROWS(GetRowsFromTable2ById(ID2))
   }
}
RETURN RESULT;
```

Table1:

```
Name   ID
====   ==
ABC    7;8;9
PQR    1;2;3
ABC    4;5;6
```

Table2:

```
ID     Class
==     =====
 1     A
 2     B
 3     C
 4     D
 5     E
 6     F
 7     G
 8     H
 9     I
```

Desired Output Table:

```
ID   Class
==   =====
4    D
5    E
6    F
7    G
8    H
```

I can implement this at business logic layer in C# but I want to implement it at data layer in stored procedure. So, that there will be only one call to the database server. Following is my progress but due to lack of SQL knowledge I am unable to proceed:

```
DECLARE @delimitedArray VARCHAR(MAX) = '4;2;3;'
DECLARE @delimiter CHAR = ';'
DECLARE @item VARCHAR(MAX)
WHILE LEN(@delimitedArray) > 0
BEGIN
 SET @item = LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@delimitedArray, 1, CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @delimitedArray) - 1));
 SET @delimitedArray = SUBSTRING(@delimitedArray, CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @delimitedArray) + 1, LEN(@delimitedArray));
 PRINT @item
END
```

Please help.

Comment: `One of its columns contains semi-colon separated values.` WHY? This is a relational database, not a JSON utility.

Comment: @AaronBertrand because I am storing an integer array in that column in form of semi-colon delimited list. This integer array is stored by a C# code in this table.

Comment: Making coding easier is not a valid reason for violating normalization. Storing multiple values like this in a single intersection violates 1NF. You are having problems because you built your table in such a way as it is a pain to deal with from the data side. Fix the ddl and the dml is simple.

Comment: I agree with everything Sean said there, apart from he spelt normalised incorrectly ;) Why aren't you using C# data tables to arrange the data before insertion into the database? With C# you can do much more. It doesn't make sense that you leave the DB to do the client layer's work...

Comment: @SeanLange I agree with you but I am not trying to make coding easier. I am trying to minimize the number of database calls from business logic. If I store semi-colon separated values in their separate table with a foreign key attached to table1 then calls to the database will increase in various functions of the system.

Comment: @JohnnyBell Because I want to minimize database calls and execute as many as possible business logic tasks at data layer.

Comment: There wouldn't be any more database calls. In fact you'd probably make less if you sorted out the client side first, and your database model. Trust me, ask any seasoned SQL professional, and they will tell you this is bad design, and in 5 years time when you've forgotten all about it or someone else needs to look at it, your legacy code will be a nightmare. If you sort it out now, and go by ISO standards, you'll save alot of hair pulling later. We only say this to help you....

Comment: I completely agree with all the previous comments, but treating your question as academic for the moment, you can google SQL SPLIT FUNCTION and find code that reproduces the SPLIT() function in SQL, and use it it to do what you want.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva I don't understand what you mean about minimizing database calls. I don't see how normalized data will increase the amount of queries. You seem to be making non-standard design decisions to deal with a performance issue that doesn't exist. This is called premature optimization and almost always results in very poor decisions.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for the advice. I rethought a lot and changed my database architecture and now it's according to 1NF and with one database call only. :)